# "Cloning" Excel File Cells (xlsx) with Color

Tags: vb.net, npoi

Using VB.NET 2019 scrub edition
Im currently Using NPOI to help interfacing with an excel document with multiple sheets.
Each rows' cells are not uniform in color.
I seem to be getting the majority of the information I need with NPOI, however the cell color is a challenge. I suppose I need to Collect the Colors from the Excel sheet first, then modify the Isheet Row Cells (which im trying to avoid writing a huge method to get the information that may not be accurate). When I call the Isheet's row colors(FillBackgroundColorColor gives me problems when its null, even when trying to write a condition for it, So i have to use FillBackgroundColor for its numeric values, all of which are either 0 or 64, which I don't understand either since everything is appearing white, and there are many more colors in the Excel File.

What Im Doing: I have an excel sheet, which I load into a XSSFWorkBook, then load the appropriate Sheet in the XSSFWorkBook to an ISheet (npoi usermodel), which I then load into a datagridview.

Main Question: How would I get the cell colors from the Excel Sheet to transfer over to my datagridview? Is there an easy way, or do it gotta Magellan this?
Secondary Questions: Should I be using a better library as an Import other than NPOI?
I'm under the impression using NPOI is free for commercial use/sales. Am I correct on this interpretation? If not whats the best commercial free alternative?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports NPOI
Imports NPOI.SS.UserModel
Imports NPOI.XSSF.UserModel
```

Uncommented version

```
 Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
    Dim wb As XSSFWorkbook
    Dim sh As ISheet
    Dim xl As FileStream = New FileStream(My.Settings.SaveFolder & "\ExcelFile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    wb = New XSSFWorkbook(xl)
    xl.Close()
    sh = wb.CloneSheet(wb.Count - 1)
    dt = New DataTable(sh.SheetName)

    Dim headerrow As IRow = sh.GetRow(0)
    For Each cell In headerrow
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.ToString())
    Next
    Dim newcol As New DataColumn With {
        .ColumnName = "Overflow"}
    dt.Columns.Add(newcol)
    
    For i = 0 To sh.PhysicalNumberOfRows - 1
        Dim sheetrow As IRow = sh.GetRow(i)

        For Each cellll As ICell In sheetrow.Cells
             If cellll.CellType = CellType.Formula Then
               cellll.SetCellType(CellType.String)
            End If
        Next

        Dim dtrow = dt.NewRow()
        dtrow.ItemArray = sheetrow.Cells.ToArray()
        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow)
    Next
    GridAccount.DataSource = dt
  End Sub
```

Commented Version

```
Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
    Dim wb As XSSFWorkbook
    Dim sh As ISheet
    Dim xl As FileStream = New FileStream(My.Settings.SaveFolder & "\ExcelFile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    wb = New XSSFWorkbook(xl)
    xl.Close()
    sh = wb.CloneSheet(wb.Count - 1)
    '  MessageBox.Show(wb.ToString)
    dt = New DataTable(sh.SheetName)

    Dim headerrow As IRow = sh.GetRow(0)
    For Each cell In headerrow
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.ToString())
        '  cell.CellStyle = wb.GetStylesSource.ToString
        MessageBox.Show(wb.GetSheetAt(wb.Count - 1).GetColumnStyle(cell.ColumnIndex).ToString)
        '  dt.Columns
    Next
    Dim newcol As New DataColumn With {
        .ColumnName = "Overflow"}
    dt.Columns.Add(newcol)
    '   MessageBox.Show(dt.Columns.Count.ToString)

    For i = 0 To sh.PhysicalNumberOfRows - 1
        Dim sheetrow As IRow = sh.GetRow(i)



        For Each cell5 As ICell In sh.GetRow(i)
            '  MessageBox.Show(cell5.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColor.ToString)
        Next

        For Each cellll As ICell In sheetrow.Cells
            '    Try
            '  MessageBox.Show(cellll.StringCellValue.ToString)
            ' sheetrow.Cells.
            '  Catch
            If cellll.CellType = CellType.Formula Then
                '  cellll.SetCellValue(cellll.)
                'Select Case (cellll.GetCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum())
                '    Case CellType.formul
                cellll.SetCellType(CellType.String)


                '    MessageBox.Show(cellll.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColor.ToString)
                '  MessageBox.Show(cellll.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor.ToString)


                'If icell.FillBackgroundColorColor.ToString = Nothing Then

                'End If

                'If cellll.CellStyle Is icell Then
                '    MessageBox.Show(cellll.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor.ToString)
                '    'End Select
                'Else
                '    MessageBox.Show(cellll.CellStyle.FillBackgroundColorColor.ToString)
                '    '  MessageBox.Show("true")
                'End If
                'If cellll.CellType = CellType.Numeric Then
                '        cellll.SetCellType(CellType.String)
            End If
            ' MessageBox.Show(cellll.NumericCellValue.ToString) Then
            '  End Try

        Next



        Dim dtrow = dt.NewRow()

        'MessageBox.Show(sheetrow.Cells.ToArray().Length.ToString)
        dtrow.ItemArray = sheetrow.Cells.ToArray()

        dt.Rows.Add(dtrow)
        '  dt.ImportRow(dtrow)
    Next
    GridAccount.DataSource = dt
    ' MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)


    'Dim rowcount = sh.LastRowNum
    'Dim counterr As Integer = 0
    'For Each row As IRow In sh
    '    If counterr = 0 Then
    '        counterr += 1
    '        Continue For
    '    End If
    '    Dim cellls As List(Of ICell) = New List(Of ICell)
    '    For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
    '        For r = 0 To rowcount
    '            cellls.Add(row.GetCell(r, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK))
    '            dt.Rows.Add(row.GetCell(r, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK))
    '        Next
    '    Next
    '    GridAccount.DataSource = dt
    'Next
    '   Dim roo As IRow = sh.GetRow(0)
    '  Dim tablename = wb.GetSheet("SheetIWant")
    '  dt = wb.GetTa

End Sub
```